# Could not hide my third child element with nth-child

Tags: jquery

here is my generated html. How do I hide my second hole card?

```
<div id="cardContainerDealer">
    <div class="card templateDealer">
        <span class="dealerCardFace"></span>
        <span class="dealerCardSuit"></span>
    </div>
<div class="card">
        <span class="dealerCardFace">8</span>
        <span class="dealerCardSuit">♣</span>
    </div>
<div class="card red">
        <span class="dealerCardFace">10</span>
        <span class="dealerCardSuit">♥</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried below but not working

```
 $("#cardContainerDealer:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

Comment: You're just missing the space to indicate children: `$("#cardContainerDealer :nth-child(2)").hide();` the equivalent of `$("#cardContainerDealer").find(":nth-child(2)").hide();` while your original code was `$("#cardContainerDealer").filter(":nth-child(2)").hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) wrong. Despite it's naming it matches siblings as childs of an element, so you need to select the class `.card` as well:

```js
$("#cardContainerDealer .card:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cardContainerDealer">
  <div class="card templateDealer">
    <span class="dealerCardFace"></span>
    <span class="dealerCardSuit"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <span class="dealerCardFace">8</span>
    <span class="dealerCardSuit">♣</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card red">
    <span class="dealerCardFace">10</span>
    <span class="dealerCardSuit">♥</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for `.card` if they are all `.card`, just `$("#cardContainerDealer :nth-child(2)").hide();`

Comment: @freedomn-m you are right, but that might traverse too far down, see: https://jsfiddle.net/johgvzsx/ the span with ♥ will be hidden as well as this is a second child of `.card`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just that my first card will be hidden instead of the second one. But still ok.

Comment: @Steve that's because `card templateDealer` is counted into the child elemtents, you could do `:nth-child(3)` instead depending if the first empty card is always present. If this is dynamic you have to implement more js logic, excluding elements from pseudo-selectors is afaik not possible with the current css spec.

Comment: `$("#cardContainerDealer :not(.templateDealer):nth-child(2)").hide();`  (note, no space between the two pseudo selectors) - or **don't give the template a `.card` class** and use the original `$("#cardContainerDealer .card:nth-child(2)").hide();`

Comment: If you want direct siblings only, use `>` not `[space]`, so my first comment above (rightly noted would affect sub-sub-children etc) could be: `$("#cardContainerDealer>:nth-child(2)").hide();`

Comment: Guys, what if I just want to hide the second card child two span only? <span class="dealerCardFace">10</span>
    <span class="dealerCardSuit">♥</span>

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery `eq` ref https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```js
$('.card').eq(1).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cardContainerDealer">
    <div class="card templateDealer">
        <span class="dealerCardFace"></span>
        <span class="dealerCardSuit"></span>
    </div>
<div class="card">
        <span class="dealerCardFace">8</span>
        <span class="dealerCardSuit">♣</span>
    </div>
<div class="card red">
        <span class="dealerCardFace">10</span>
        <span class="dealerCardSuit">♥</span>
    </div>
</div>
```